# iPhone-Grouped Table View adding two radio buttons for each row

Tags: iphone

I want to display two radio buttons in each row and i need to set action for two buttons i was facing problem in setting the actions and display text and radio buttons in correct position for each row, If some one help please.

Here is my code

Thanks in advance

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//@class CustomCellQuestionnaireList;

@interface QuestionnaireListView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate> 
{
  //NSMutableArray *dataArray;
  UITableView       *theTableView;
  UILabel           *lbl_child;
  UILabel           *lbl_title;
  UILabel           *lbl_time;
  NSMutableArray    *tableData;//will be storing data that will be displayed in table
  NSMutableArray    *tableSubData;
  //NSMutableArray  *tableTitleArray;
  //CustomCellQuestionnaireList *cell;
    IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *myButton2;
    BOOL isSelected;
    IBOutlet UIView *view1;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveBtn;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *discardBtn;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *okBtn;
    //IBOutlet UIToolbar *m_toolBar;
    //IBOutlet UIToolbar *m_okToolBar;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_child;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_title;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_time;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView * theTableView;
//@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *tableSubData;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *view1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIBarButtonItem *saveBtn;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIBarButtonItem *discardBtn;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIBarButtonItem *okBtn;
//@property(nonatomic, retain)UIToolbar *m_toolBar;
//@property(nonatomic, retain)UIToolbar *m_okToolBar;

- (IBAction)onClickLeftArrow;
- (IBAction)onClickRightArrow;
//- (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)selectRadioButon:(UIButton *)button;
//-(IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation QuestionnaireListView

@synthesize tableData, tableSubData;
@synthesize theTableView;
//@synthesize dataArray;
@synthesize lbl_child;
@synthesize lbl_title;
@synthesize lbl_time;
@synthesize view1;
@synthesize saveBtn;
@synthesize discardBtn;
@synthesize okBtn;
//@synthesize m_toolBar;
//@synthesize m_okToolBar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
        UIButton *button1 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"saveBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 34)];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(saveBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button1 setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
        NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem1];
        //[self setToolbarItems:toolBarItems];

        UIButton *button2 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 66, 34)];
        //[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(home:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[button2 setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];



        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button2];
        [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem2];
        button2.hidden = YES;
        //[self setToolbarItems:toolBarItems];

        UIButton *button3 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 66, 34)];
        //[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(okBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[button4 setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button3];
        [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem3];
        button3.hidden = YES;

        UIButton *button4 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"discardBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 66, 34)];
        [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(discardBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button4 setTitle:@"Discard" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4];
        [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem4];
        [self setToolbarItems:toolBarItems];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[self.theTableView.layer setCornerRadius:30.0];
    // create button
    //UIButton* logOutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; // left-pointing shape!
    UIButton *logOutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:100];
    [logOutButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exitBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [logOutButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem* logOutItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logOutButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logOutItem;


    [lbl_title setText:@"Store View"];
    [lbl_title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    //NSString *date = [[NSDate date] dateFormat];
    NSString *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
    [lbl_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date]];
    [lbl_time setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    // add to toolbar, or to a navbar (you should only have one of these!)
    //[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:backItem]];

    //tableTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//  [tableTitleArray addObject:@"General"];
//  [tableTitleArray addObject:@"Product"];

    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableData addObject:@"Is the floor clean?"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Are the food items stacked in freezer?"];

    tableSubData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableData addObject:@"Has the snow been cleared at the entrance?"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Are milk products available"];


    view1.hidden = YES;
    //m_okToolBar.hidden= YES;

    //m_toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    //m_toolBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; m_toolBar.alpha = 0.7;
    //UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nextBtn.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(customButtonHandler:)]];
    // btn.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 30, 30);
    //[btn release];
}


-(void)saveBtn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    view1.hidden = NO;
    UIButton *button1 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"saveBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 105, 34)];
    //[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(saveBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[button1 setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
    NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem1];

    UIButton *button2 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIButton *button3 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIButton *button4 =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 34)];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(okBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button2 setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button2];
    [toolBarItems addObject:barButtonItem2];
    [self setToolbarItems:toolBarItems];



    button1.hidden = YES;
    button2.hidden = NO;
    button3.hidden = YES;
    button4.hidden = YES;

}

-(void)okBtn:(id)sender {
    view1.hidden = YES;

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] animated:YES];

}


//-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
//{
//
//  //VizueraQAppDelegate *appDelegate = (VizueraQAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//  //[appDelegate RefreshIndexArray];
//  
//}
- (void)logoutButtonTouched {   
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)onClickLeftArrow {  

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)onClickRightArrow { 

    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // release the array
//  self.dataArray = nil;
//  tableData = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    //[cell release];
    [tableData release];
    [tableSubData release];
    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark - UIViewController delegate methods

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // invoke super's implementation to do the Right Thing, but also release the input controller since we can do that  
    // In practice this is unlikely to be used in this application, and it would be of little benefit,
    // but the principle is the important thing.
    //
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


//- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
//{
//  return YES;
//}


#pragma mark - UITableView delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableData!=nil && tableSubData!=nil) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return [tableData count];
    }
    else {
        return [tableSubData count];
    }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 74;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}

//- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //return ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]]);

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        NSString *returnString = @"";
        if (tableData!=nil && section == 0) {
            returnString =  @"General";
        }
        else if(section == 1){
            returnString = @"Product";
        }
        return returnString;
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    //CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
        //cell = (CustomCell *)[[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.tag=[indexPath row];
        NSInteger tagCount;
        myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 48, 20, 20)]; 
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.tag = ++tagCount;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
        tagCount++;

        myButton2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 48, 20, 20)]; 
        [myButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton2.tag = tagCount;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton2];
        tagCount++;

        /*UILabel *m_label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        m_label.text = @"Yes";
        m_label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        m_label.frame = CGRectMake(15, 48, 40, 40);
        [m_label release]; */

        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(35, 49, 30, 15);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
        //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        label.text = @"Yes";
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        label.tag = 10;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        CGRect labelRect1 = CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 15);
        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect1];
        //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        label1.text = @"No";
        label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        label1.tag = 10;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
        [label1 release];
    }

    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if([tableData count]>indexPath.row)
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);


    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)selectRadioButon:(UIButton *)button{

    for (UIButton *but in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && ![but isEqual:button]) {
            [but setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
    if (!button.selected) {
        button.selected = !button.selected;
    }
    if (isSelected) {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isSelected = NO;
    }
    else {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioBtn_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isSelected = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your "initWithFrame" codes inside the if(cell == nil) { } for when you're drawing your table cells and move all the "setting" UI elements outside that if.

See my code example here:

[Can't Change Transparent BG in Custom UITableViewCell (Grouped Table View)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824770/cant-change-transparent-bg-in-custom-uitableviewcell-grouped-table-view/6825570#6825570)